# How my website submit email to my email using submit button for inquiry

Tags: html

This is the code of my website

```
<form class="form"> 
    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone No:">
    <textarea class="message" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </form>
```

Comment: This is only the front-end part of your code, what have you tried for the back-end?

Comment: I dont know how to add the backend of this code? what should I use? can I send to you the files of my website?

Comment: Edit your question and post it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form class="form" action="emailSubmit.php" method="POST">
```

You can also add a function to return true or false for validating input data

```
<form class="form" action="emailSubmit.php method="POST" onsubmit="return validateData()">
```

When submit is pressed, validate data returns true if input valid and send data through POST to php file, false if invalid and does nothing

Ofcourse this goes along with javascript functions, php script and database to insert queries to